# powershell script to start new powershell window with ffmpeg commands

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have two live streams that I am converting using ffmpeg commands. one stream is using hls input stream other is using mpeg stream. Right now i am openning two powershell windows for each ffmpeg command given below. My problem is over time i need to re-issue these commands on server to restart conversions (currently 2 in future maybe 30). To achieve this I am trying to write a Ps script that i will invoke using windows task scheduler. I am stuck on how to fire below commands with new powershell window/process.

ffmpeg -re -i http://nsgr.hls.iptvdc.com/islambox/732/play.m3u8 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ab 48k -ac 2 -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.2/live/naja83

ffmpeg -re -i http://bgsf.redist.iptvdc.com/islambox/969ecd6cb9e136ed0fd042ccf5cc057b -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ab 48k -ac 2 -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://ib12.islambox.tv/live/najam84

## Script so far

```
#kill all powershell and ffmepg process- Mega reset

get-process -name ffmpeg | stop-process
get-process -name powershell | Stop-Process


#then issue ffmpeg commands for every stream we have using its own powershell process/window


#if i do start powershell it gives me error for -re flag required by ffmpeg same goes with start-process
ffmpeg -re -i http://nsgr.hls.iptvdc.com/islambox/732/play.m3u8 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ab 48k -ac 2 -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.2/live/naja83

ffmpeg -re -i http://bgsf.redist.iptvdc.com/islambox/969ecd6cb9e136ed0fd042ccf5cc057b -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ab 48k -ac 2 -strict -2 -f flv
```

Comment: `get-process -name powershell | Stop-Process` I think, that just kill your own PowerShell process.

Comment: ok i will comment that out and kill only ffmpeg process provided i can lauch two of them for my two streams. how can i do that using powershell script?

Comment: Does provided command line working, if you type it in `CMD` window?

Comment: yes working in cmd and powershell both. ffmpeg is added into environment varriable

Comment: `Start-Process ffmpeg '-re -i http://nsgr.hls.iptvdc.com/islambox/732/play.m3u8 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ab 48k -ac 2 -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.2/live/naja83'`

Comment: @PetSerAl check the result
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the 
file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process 'ffmpeg -re -i http://bgsf.hls.iptvdc.com/islambox/732/play.m3u8 - ...

Comment: You place `'` in wrong place.

Comment: @PetSerAl with correct place still same issue